# Edit multiple QT widgets (GUI) in QT Creator

Tags: qt, qtwidgets

I have a general GUI editing question using QT. We can create GUI applications using the QT form view where we can edit the layout graphically. And then we can swtich to the code to fine tune. Problem is i can Edit only the main window GUI. Now if i want to create another dialog e.g, pop up, i could only do so from code. Can you recommend any example or direct to the QT Documentation which shows how to edit multiple widget/dialog windows graphically using IDE.

I looked through the questions asked here which neatly explains how to open a new dialog window with code examples. But i could not find any example showing how to edit multiple layouts using QT's graphical editor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add other forms to your application, right click on the project name in the project tree view, then select "Add New", then under the Qt category look for "Qt Designer Form Class", like in this picture:

[image]

Follow the rest of the wizard (will ask the class name) and in the end you should find tree more files in your treeview with extensions .h, .cpp and a .ui. Click on the latter one to open the designer and edit the form from there.